# innodb Mysql database keeps getting tables damaged

Tags: mysql, dictionary, innodb, mamp

Somehow, using MAMP PRO in my macbook certain two tables just disappear after a while.  This has just started a couple of weeks a go and I can't find why.  I read the logs and it points me to the INNODB troubleshooting the website tells this error

> [ERROR] Cannot find or open table dbcobros/seguimiento from the
>   internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table
>   exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
>   files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files of
>   InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database? or,
>   the table contains indexes that this version of the engine doesn't
>   support.

is an example of out-of-sync data dictionary.  I followed the advice and deleted the .frm orphaned file but I still couldn't recreate the table, so I deleted the database and created one again, and run an SQL dump I had.  After a couple of minutes it happened again!

How this happened? How can I re-sync the data dictionary?  Is this a problem with the mysql installation of the MAMP?  I'm about to go into production with my application but now with this error I'm not sure if it will replicate in the production servers and they will lose critical data.  Please help!

Comment: innodb stores the DB data in `idbdata` files, regardless of what the DB name is. The .frm is only kept around for the table definitions. Is something trashing your ibdata and ib_logfile files?

Comment: that's the thing; I don't know! I recently upgraded to MacOSX Lion, I don't know if that upgrade touched any of the MAMP files; could it be that?

Comment: hey did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue after installing MAMP Pro...